# mongo-express pod doesn't start properly

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

i faced a problem while starting mongo-express pod in k8s cluster "[MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option 'useUnifiedTopology: true' to the MongoClient constructor."
i tried many solutions and the same error. and this is my files

configMap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
  options: '{"useUnifiedTopology":true}'
```

mongo.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
```

mongo-express.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        env:
        - name: MONGO_OPTIONS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-configmap
              key: options
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-configmap
              key: database_url
```

Comment: Put the code as Text not as Images.

Comment: I have done now, files appear as a text in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

This warning message is not related to k8s. This is related to change in js driver for mongodb server discovery.

There is an open issue in [mongo-express GitHub repository](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/832) for running mongo express in k8s cluster.

As per this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/720#issuecomment-871040716), you should also set `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL` environment variable.

Comment: it's not a warning message, it's a error message, the container failed to start because of this error,
and about 'ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL', yes I have put it but I only showed the relevant section on my error

Comment: The exact  env var name is `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL` and not `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER`